# Sonar: Dodgy - Load of known null value (try with resources)

Tags: java, findbugs

Sonar is complaining about a "Load of known null value" on the last bracket of the following private method, so I assume it's something in the close() method triggered by the try with resources statement..

What am I doing wrong?

```
private boolean statementHasResults(PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
    try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            int result = resultSet.getInt(TOTAL);
            return result > 0;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a findbugs rule, shown by sonarqube but it is definitely something on findbugs side.

Comment: And your first analysis seems right that the try with resources is probably messing up findbugs analysis as it relies only on bytecode and this construction generates a load of bytecode instructions. You should look up for findbugs open issues.

Comment: I tried this method with FindBugs and see no FindBugs error reports in this code. Which Java compiler are you using (javac? ecj? Which version exactly?) Are you using any source/bytecode processors (like Lombok or probably AspectJ)? They are known to generate bytecode which may produce bogus FindBugs warnings. If it's possible, add a link to download the generated classfile (`.class`), I will take a closer look what's going on.